# Approximating the roots of $\sum_{k=1}^n{\sin{\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}}$ for large $n$ and large $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, roots, approximation

Here is the graph of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin{\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}}$ for $n=1000$.

[image]

There appear to be roots, or actually "clusters" of roots, at:

$x\approx2.17n$
$x\approx5.05n$
$x\approx8.07n$
$x\approx11.2n$
$x\approx14.3n$
$x\approx17.4n$
$x\approx20.5n$
$x\approx23.7n$
$x\approx26.9n$

It seems that, for large $n$ and large $x$, the gap between clusters is $\pi n$.

> **For large $n$ and large $x$, what pattern emerges for the locations of these clusters of roots, and why?**

My attempt:

Expressing the series as a Riemann sum, we are looking for the values of $x$ such that

$$n\int_0^1{\sin{\left(\frac{x/n}{t}\right)}}dt=0$$

What values of $x$ satisfy this equation?

Comment: For $a>0$, we need the values where $$\text{Ci}(a)=\text{sinc}(a)=\frac{\sin(a)}a$$ with the [Cosine integral function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cosintegral) and the [sinc](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sinc) function. However, there is likely no closed form for $a$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\frac{x}{k}=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{x/n}{k/n}\approx n\int_0^1\sin\frac{x/n}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$Is this what you meant? I'm a bit confused about your approximation. Furthermore, the multiplication by $n$ might mean that the approximation is unjustified, depending on the error rate of the Riemann sum/integral approximation - if it's $O(1/n)$, or slower, then it's no good

Comment: If $x=\pi m\cdot n!$ Then it is always a root, regardless of the size of $n$, for $m\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: @FShrike I have corrected the question (under "my attempt").

Comment: I still think we need a precise estimate on the error rate of the sum-->integral passage, but I don't know how to do this off the top of my hand. Seriously, if the error decays as slow as or slower than $O(1/n)$ the approximation will be useless (I think)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approximating the Sum**

Let's say that $x=\lambda n$
$$\newcommand{\Ci}{\operatorname{Ci}}
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac xk\right)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)\frac1n\tag{1b}\\
&\sim n\int_0^1\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1c}\\
&=n\lambda\int_\lambda^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1d}\\
&=n\lambda\left(\frac{\sin(\lambda)}\lambda+\int_\lambda^\infty\frac{\cos(u)}u\,\mathrm{d}u\right)\tag{1e}\\
&=n\lambda\left(\frac{\sin(\lambda)}\lambda-\Ci(\lambda)\right)\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ $x=\lambda n$
$\text{(1b):}$ multiply by $n\cdot\frac1n$
$\text{(1c):}$ approximate a Riemann Sum with an integral
$\text{(1d):}$ substitute $u\mapsto\frac\lambda u$
$\text{(1e):}$ integrate by parts
$\text{(1f):}$ $\Ci(\lambda)=-\int_\lambda^\infty\frac{\cos(u)}u\,\mathrm{d}u$ by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral)

[image]

Multiply the numbers on both axes by $1000$ and this matches [the image in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYHP2.png) pretty well.

---

**Approximating the Roots of $\bf{(1f)}$**

Integration by parts gives
$$
\hspace{-12pt}\small\Ci(\lambda)=\frac{\sin(\lambda)}{\lambda}-\frac{\cos(\lambda)}{\lambda^2}-\frac{2\sin(\lambda)}{\lambda^3}+\frac{6\cos(\lambda)}{\lambda^4}+\frac{24\sin(\lambda)}{\lambda^5}-120\int_\lambda^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u^6}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag2
$$
Thus,
$$
\sin(\lambda)-\lambda\Ci(\lambda)=\frac{\cos(\lambda)}{\lambda}+\frac{2\sin(\lambda)}{\lambda^2}-\frac{6\cos(\lambda)}{\lambda^3}-\frac{24\sin(\lambda)}{\lambda^4}+O\!\left(\frac1{\lambda^5}\right)\tag3
$$
Using the first term of $(3)$, the roots of $\sin(\lambda)-\lambda\Ci(\lambda)$ should tend to the roots of $\cos(\lambda)=0$; that is $\lambda=\left(m+\frac12\right)\!\pi$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Using the first two terms of $(3)$, the roots should tend to the roots of $\tan\left(\lambda-\frac\pi2\right)=\frac2\lambda$; that is, $\lambda\approx\left(m+\frac12\right)\!\pi+\frac2{\left(m+\frac12\right)\pi}$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
m&\lambda:\text{root of }(3)&\left(m+\frac12\right)\pi&\left(m+\frac12\right)\pi+\frac2{\left(m+\frac12\right)\pi}\\\hline
0&\phantom{0}2.1562352499&\phantom{0}1.5707963268&\phantom{0}2.8440358715\\
1&\phantom{0}5.0465185699&\phantom{0}4.7123889804&\phantom{0}5.1368021620\\
2&\phantom{0}8.0813348344&\phantom{0}7.8539816340&\phantom{0}8.1086295429\\
3&11.1660275642&10.9955742876&11.1774656511\\
4&14.2728635755&14.1371669412&14.2786380017\\
5&17.3912167409&17.2787595947&17.3945086443\\
6&20.5162494516&20.4203522483&20.5182937518\\
7&23.6454749210&23.5619449019&23.6468275382\\
8&26.7774943010&26.7035375555&26.7784339993\\
9&29.9114642648&29.8451302091&29.9121428167
\end{array}
$$

---

**Estimating the Error in Step $\bf{(1c)}$**

For any $\epsilon\gt0$,
$$
\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\epsilon n\rfloor}\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)\frac1n\,\right|\le\epsilon\tag4
$$
and
$$
\left|\,\int_0^\epsilon\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\right|\le\epsilon\tag5
$$
The error in approximating
$$
\sum_{k=\lfloor\epsilon n\rfloor+1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)\frac1n=\int_\epsilon^1\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag6
$$
is the variation of the integrand times the step size. For $u\in[\epsilon,1]$ the variation of $\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)$ is bounded by $\frac{2\lambda}{\pi\epsilon}$ and the step size is $\frac1n$. Thus, if we use $\epsilon=\left(\frac{\lambda}{\pi n}\right)^{1/2}$, we get the error in approximating
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)\frac1n=\int_0^1\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag7
$$
is bounded by
$$
2\epsilon+\frac{2\lambda}{\pi\epsilon n}=4\left(\frac{\lambda}{\pi n}\right)^{1/2}\tag8
$$
This is sufficient for finding the values of $\lambda$ where the sum crosses $0$.

---

**Asymptotic Series for the Roots of $\bf{(3)}$**

We can extend $(3)$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sin(\lambda)-\lambda\operatorname{Ci}(\lambda)\\
&=\cos(\lambda)\left(\frac1{\lambda}-\frac6{\lambda^3}+\frac{120}{\lambda^5}-\frac{5040}{\lambda^7}+\frac{362880}{\lambda^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{\lambda^{11}}\right)\right)\\
&{}+{}\sin(\lambda)\left(\frac2{\lambda^2}-\frac{24}{\lambda^4}+\frac{720}{\lambda^6}-\frac{40320}{\lambda^8}+\frac{3628800}{\lambda^{10}}+O\!\left(\frac1{\lambda^{12}}\right)\right)\tag9\\
\end{align}
$$
which has roots when
$$
\begin{align}
\tan\left(\lambda-\frac\pi2\right)
&=-\cot(\lambda)\tag{10a}\\
&=\frac{\frac2{\lambda^2}-\frac{24}{\lambda^4}+\frac{720}{\lambda^6}-\frac{40320}{\lambda^8}+\frac{3628800}{\lambda^{10}}+O\!\left(\frac1{\lambda^{12}}\right)}{\frac1{\lambda}-\frac6{\lambda^3}+\frac{120}{\lambda^5}-\frac{5040}{\lambda^7}+\frac{362880}{\lambda^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{\lambda^{11}}\right)}\tag{10b}\\
&=\frac2\lambda-\frac{12}{\lambda^3}+\frac{408}{\lambda^5}-\frac{26352}{\lambda^7}+\frac{2635488}{\lambda^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{\lambda^{11}}\right)\tag{10c}
\end{align}
$$
which leads to the recursion
$$
\hspace{-12pt}\lambda=\left(m+\frac12\right)\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac2\lambda-\frac{12}{\lambda^3}+\frac{408}{\lambda^5}-\frac{26352}{\lambda^7}+\frac{2635488}{\lambda^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{\lambda^{11}}\right)\right)\tag{11}
$$
which, upon iterating and setting $\mu=\left(m+\tfrac12\right)\pi$, leads to the asymptotic series
$$
\lambda=\mu+\frac2\mu-\frac{56}{3\mu^3}+\frac{8936}{15\mu^5}-\frac{3741824}{105\mu^7}+\frac{1055734496}{315\mu^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{\mu^{11}}\right)\tag{12}
$$
The first two terms of $(12)$ were used to generate the table following $(3)$. $(12)$ is not very good for small $m$, which is normal for asymptotic series, but is much better for large $m$:
$$
\begin{array}{r|r}
m&\scriptsize\lambda:\sin(\lambda)+\lambda\operatorname{Ci}(\lambda)=0&\text{value from }(12)\\\hline
0&2.1562352499&56115.9471256\\
1&5.0465185699&7.4488639194\\
2&8.0813348344&8.1001763470\\
3&11.1660275642&11.1667233185\\
4&14.2728635755&14.2729191745\\
5&17.3912167409&17.3912238551\\
6&20.5162494516&20.5162507055\\
7&23.6454749210&23.6454752000\\
8&26.7774943010&26.7774943752\\
9&29.9114642648&29.9114642874\\
10&33.0468477414&33.0468477492\\
15&48.7355988299&48.7355988300\\
20&64.4336346713&64.4336346713\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Could you justify the integral approximation viz. my comments underneath the OP? Specifically, we need to show the error rate to decay *strictly faster* than $O(1/n)$

Comment: I will attempt to address that in my answer when I return.

Comment: I have added an explanation. The factor of $n$ in front of the sum and integral does not affect the point at which the sum and integral cross $0$.

Comment: Nice analysis, and thank you for notifying me. However, the factor of $n$ in front of both the sum and integral explodes the error bound to $Cn^{1/2}$ for some $C\gt0$ and that doesn't decay as $n\to\infty$. Then, for large $n$, I don't see why we can expect our approximate roots of $\frac{\sin\lambda}{\lambda}-\operatorname{Ci}\lambda$ to remain approximate roots upon multiplication by $n$

Comment: Because, whatever error in the root there may be due to sum/integral approximation, the factor of $n$ might enlarge this error outside of a small neighbourhood of $0$. I mean, clearly your approximation *is* good from numerical evidence, but (as a student) I'm curious to see why it should work so well

Comment: The values of $\lambda$ where $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)=0$ and $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)=0$ are the same. The values of $\lambda$ where $n\int_0^1\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u=0$ and $\int_0^1\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u=0$ are the same. So, for computing the points of crossing $0$, we can consider $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin\left(\frac{\lambda n}k\right)$ and $\int_0^1\sin\left(\frac\lambda u\right)\,\mathrm{d}u$.

Comment: As shown, the difference of these is bounded by $4\left(\frac{\lambda}{\pi n}\right)^{1/2}$ which does go to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus, the places where the sum crosses $0$ are tending to the places where the integral crosses $0$.

Comment: "However, the factor of $n$ in front of both the sum and integral explodes the error bound to $Cn^{1/2}$ for some $C\gt0$ and that doesn't decay as $n\to\infty$." Indeed the error explodes as $n^{1/2}$, but the value of the functions explode as $n$, so the relative error in the functions, after dividing by $n$ to make the functions actually converge, is on the order of $n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I see. That makes more sense now

Comment: Interesting problem, isn't it ? Cheers :-)

Comment: In terms of polynomilas, as you did, I think that I obtained something which works decently.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1{\sin{\left(\frac{x}{nt}\right)}}dt=\sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-\frac{x }{n}\,\text{Ci}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
Let $y=\frac{x}{n}$ and you look for the zeros of function
$$f(y)=\sin (y)-y \,\text{Ci}(y)$$ Using @robjohn's answer, the first iterate of Newton ot Halley method around $y=\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi$ is given by

$$y_{(2,3)}=\frac{(-1)^m}{K_m} \qquad \text{with} \qquad K_m=\text{Ci}\left(\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi \right)$$

Using instead Householder method
$$y_{(4)}=t\,\,\frac{ (-1)^m \left(t^2-6\right)K_m^2-2 t K_m +(-1)^m} {-6 tK_m^3 + (-1)^m t^2K_m^2-2 tK_m +(-1)^m }\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi$$

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 m & y_{(2,3)} & y_{(4)} &\text{solution} \\
 0 & 2.1186411 & 2.1582777 &  2.1562352 \\
 1 & 5.0401305 & 5.0465284 &  5.0465115 \\
 2 & 8.0793538 & 8.0813336 &  8.0813344 \\
 3 & 11.165197 & 11.166027 &  11.166028 \\
 4 & 14.272446 & 14.272863 &  14.272864 \\
 5 & 17.390979 & 17.391217 &  17.391217 \\
 6 & 20.516102 & 20.516249 &  20.516249 \\
 7 & 23.645378 & 23.645475 &  23.645475 \\
 8 & 26.777427 & 26.777494 &  26.777494 \\
 9 & 29.911416 & 29.911464 &  29.911464 \\
 10 & 33.046811 & 33.046848 &  33.046848
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using $y_{(2,3)}$, the asymptotic distance between two roots is given by
$$\Delta_{(m+1,m)}=\pi -\frac{2}{\pi  m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)$$

**Edit**

Another solution is to let
$$y=\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi+x$$ Then expand as series around $x=0$ and follow by a series reversion to have
$$x=w+(-1)^m \frac{w^3 (2 t-w)}{12 t^2 \,K_m }+O(w^5)\qquad \text{with} \qquad w=-t+\frac {(1)^m} {K_m} $$ which is simpler, better than $y_{(2,3)}$ but worse than $y_{(4)}$.

For $m=0$, it will give $y=2.14916$ and, for $m=1$, $y=5.04619$

**Update**

Using
$$t=(2m+1)\frac \pi 2 \qquad \text{and } \qquad L=\text{Ci}(t)$$ the series expansion of $f(y)$ is
$$f(y)=\Big[(-1)^m-t\,L\Big]-L (y-t)+\frac{(-1)^m}{6t}\sum_{n=3}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \,  P_n(t) \, (y-t)^n$$ where the first polynomials $P_n(t)$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(t) \\
 3 & 1 \\
 4 & \frac{1}{2 t} \\
 5 & \frac{3}{10 t^2}-\frac{1}{20}\\
 6 & \frac{1}{5 t^3}-\frac{1}{30 t} \\
 7 & \frac{1}{7 t^4}-\frac{1}{42 t^2}+\frac{1}{840} \\
 8 & \frac{3}{28 t^5}-\frac{1}{56 t^3}+\frac{1}{1120 t}\\
 9 & \frac{1}{12 t^6}-\frac{1}{72 t^4}+\frac{1}{1440
   t^2}-\frac{1}{60480} \\
 10 & \frac{1}{15 t^7}-\frac{1}{90 t^5}+\frac{1}{1800 t^3}-\frac{1}{75600
   t} \\
 11 & \frac{3}{55 t^8}-\frac{1}{110 t^6}+\frac{1}{2200 t^4}-\frac{1}{92400
   t^2}+\frac{1}{6652800} \\
 12 & \frac{1}{22 t^9}-\frac{1}{132 t^7}+\frac{1}{2640 t^5}-\frac{1}{110880
   t^3}+\frac{1}{7983360 t}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Considering now
$$g(z)=a_0+a_1 \,z +\sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n\,z^n $$ and using series reversion
$$z=-\frac{a_0}{a_1}+\frac{a_0^3 a_3}{a_1^4}-\frac{a_0^4 a_4}{a_1^5}-\frac{a_0^5 \left(3 a_3^2-a_1 a_5\right)}{a_1^7}+\frac{a_0^6 (7 a_3 a_4-a_1 a_6)}{a_1^8}+\cdots$$

Considering the expansion up to $O\big[(y-t)^{12}\big]$ , replacing the coefficients and computing

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
m &\text{estimate} &\text{solution} \\
 0 & \color{red}{2.156}0726691988474991 &  2.1562352499207028655 \\
 1 & \color{red}{5.0465185}531800573819 &  5.0465185698610751842 \\
 2 & \color{red}{8.0813348343}087486866 &  8.0813348343961138711 \\
 3 & \color{red}{11.1660275642}19194987 &  11.166027564221116458 \\
 4 & \color{red}{14.272863575496}435334 &  14.272863575496531499 \\
 5 & \color{red}{17.39121674085500}0157 &  17.391216740855008394 \\
 6 & \color{red}{20.51624945162485}3514 &  20.516249451624854543 \\
 7 & \color{red}{23.645474921006132}644 &  23.645474921006132814 \\
 8 & \color{red}{26.777494301026216}871 &  26.777494301026216906 \\
 9 & \color{red}{29.91146426477264437}0 &  29.911464264772644379 \\
 10 & \color{red}{33.04684774143358785}0 &  33.046847741433587853
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: (+1) Your approximations are closer than the ones I've given. I have better asymptotic approximations: good for large roots, but bad for smaller roots.

Comment: @robjohn. Very nice and elegant new part in your answer !

Comment: Something is amiss with the asymptotic expansion you posted. Compute $(y_m-\mu-\frac2\mu)\mu^3$: for $m=100$, it gives $-18.6606941195$; for $m=1000$, it gives $-18.6666063669$, for $m=10000$, it gives $-18.6666660631$. This indicates that $-\frac{56}{3\mu^3}$ is the correct next term rather than $-\frac{18}{\mu^3}$.

Comment: @robjohn. You are most than right ! Even a polynomial regression based on the first $100$ values  gives $-18.666006$ $(\sigma=0.000033)$. I deleted that part. Thanks and cheers.